# Is the search bar in desktop Unity 8 really going to be on the right side?

Tags: unity, unity-next

I noticed that, at least in the tablet version of Unity 8, the search bar is on the right side of the screen. However, people keep telling that the desktop version will come afterwards, so I don't know if that's the intended place for it to be across versions. I hope not, because it's a major UI problem.

This is the way Windows 8 does it, and it's terrible, because as you type on it (on the right side), the results appear on the *left* side, so your eyes have to move across the screen all the time, especially if your screen is a large one.

I know one can ask "but isn't that where search bars have been all along? Firefox and Windows Explorer etc.

Well, not quite. On these programs, it's intended that you finish your search key and then type Enter and only so look for the results. Unity's search bar, however, shows results dynamically, so you always want to look at the results, so you know if you can press Enter without having to write the whole sentence, and you also want to look at what you're typing, so you know there are no typos.

That being said, I wanted to know if this is really where the search bar will be and if it will not spread across the top part of the screen (that would be a good solution, since "Home Scope" and other scope titles don't need to be showing when you're typing). If that's final, then I will fill a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is that Unity will adapt itself to the different sort of screen it is running on and will change the location of the search text area so it is different on a phone and a laptop.